# Proving Inequality using Induction.

Tags: proof-writing, induction

I am trying to prove the following statement:

> For every nonnegative integer $n$, $1+6n \le 7^n$.

I did the base case where $n=0$ but am having trouble manipulating the inductive step. So far I have $7^n+6$. I need that $6$ to be a $7$ so I can have $7^{n+1}$. I am not sure how to make that happen though.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

$7^n+6\leq7^n+7\leq7^n+7^n\leq2\cdot7^n\leq7\cdot7^n=7^{n+1}$ if $n\geq1$

Comment: Can you keep manipulating that right side simply because its an inequality? 7^n +6 is for sure less than 7^n+7 and so on. Thank you!

Comment: @Vasi Well, you can keep manipulating expressions if the inferences you make are true.

Comment: @Vasi If you want to prove $A\le B$, the most common approach is by doing something like $A\le a\le b\le c\le B$, where all the inequality steps are known to hold, which proves that $A\le B$.

Comment: Thank you this helps a lot, now must my base case be for n=1 and not n=0?

Comment: @Vasi The result is true for $n\geq0$. Hence the base case would be $n=0$.